# Get file name using xsl

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

How can I get the file name using xsl 1.0?

I tried

```
<xsl:value-of select="base-uri()" />
```

but got **"Fatal Error! Could not find function: base-uri"**

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There is no such XPath function, or XSLT extension to XPath function to do this in XSLT v1/XPath v1.

It is quite possible for there to be no file, and even if there is no reason for the XSLT engine to have that file name (consider loading the file content into a buffer, parsing the buffer into a DOM and then passing the DOM to the XSLT processor).

You will need to pass the filename into the processor to be available as a parameter in the transform.

Comment: Annoying if you just want a 'created using style sheet x ' comment :-(

Comment: -1: there is such a function, in XPath 2.0 (see the other answer)

Comment: @NormanGray: The end of the question makes it clear that this is XSLT v1, so the presence of such a V2 function is irrelevant.

Comment: @Richard: aha, quite right -- I didn't spot the qualification in the question (unfortunately, I don't seem able to undo the downvote unless the answer is edited).

Comment: @NormanGray: there was one outstanding typo, and clarification never hurts so now edited.

Answer (score 36):

**`base-uri()` is a standard XPath 2.0 function**, so when running XSLT 1.0 this function will be unavailable.

**In XSLT 1.0 the filename (of what?) may be passed as a parameter** for the transformation.

**Do note** that it isn't always possible to produce a filename for a stylesheet or for an XML document -- either or both may be residing in memory without an associated file.

It is not clear from the problem which filename must be produced.

**Here is how to find filenames in XPath 2.0 / XSLT 2.0**:

The filename of the current document:

```
 base-uri()
```

The filename of the current stylesheet module:

```
  base-uri(document(''))
```