# Include the file name of the xsd schema I am processing with xslt

Tags: xsd, xslt-2.0

Hello
I am generating Objective-C class files with Saxon via XSLT and in a comment header would like to include information as to which xsd was used for their creation. Is there any way I can access the current filename during an xslt transformation?

Would be great if anyone had an idea...thanks!

Comment: This suggests that filenames or other [parameters can be passed in](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/582957/get-file-name-using-xsl)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming XSLT/XPath 2.0 or later you can use `document-uri(/)` http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-document-uri to find the URI of the input document and if you only want the file name then you could use `tokenize(document-uri(/), '/')[last()]`.